# npm postinstall fails with multiple commands

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line-interface, npm, post-install

Inside my `composer.json`, there's a `postinstall` hook setup like the following:

```
"scripts" : {
    "dist" :        "node dist; node_modules/.bin/doccoh src/package.js",
    "postinstall" : "node_modules/.bin/grunt setup || true; node_modules/.bin/bower install",
    "start" :       "node server.js"
}
```

Whenever I run it (on Win from Git/Gnu Bash CLI), I end with

> `command not found. either the command was written wrong or couldn't be found`

*Rough translation from German CLI error.*

I tried splitting it into multiple `;`/semicolon separated parts and first `cd` into that directory, but it simply ends up with the same error message. Replacing the whole `postinstall` command set with a simple `ls` does work. So I *guess* the problem might be the semicolon separation or a wrong usage of commands. But overall I got no idea what's wrong.

Note: I got `grunt-cli` version 0.1.9 and `grunt` version 0.4.1 installed globally.

Comment: This may be a bit late, but: You can install `grunt`, `grunt-cli` and `bower` locally (!) and then drop the path (`node_modules/.bin`) from your `package.json`. NPM will find `grunt` and `bower` if they are installed inside `node_modules`: https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html (section "ENVIRONMENT")

Comment: @svckr +1 dropping the `node_modules/.bin` part did the trick for me.

Comment: @svckr Do you want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 33):

I'm a bit late to answer, but if you're on Windows, multiple commands on a single line are executed with the use of &&

```
postinstall: "some command && some other -c"
```

Comment: do you know of a way to do this with cross-platform support?

Comment: @Plato for future reference, the `&&` operator works both on windows and linux. still, the commands probably will not be compatible (a very few commands can be used with the same syntax on linux and windows). the safest way to run multiple instructions would be to create a JS script and run it with the node runtime, like this: `"postinstall": "node ./postinstallscript.js"`

Comment: Not working if you have multi command by adding &&, i do not know why!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this looking for something and thought this may help other people. I have found it easier to move to postinstall.js files as things get a little complicated. This makes it easier to deal with moving forward.

Comment: Would mind filing an [edit] and describing your process a bit more in detail? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the sample in `postinstall.js`